# Consulta SQL por campo y última actualizacion

Tags: sql, datatables, subconsultas

Necesito ayuda en la siguiente solución.

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
       Productos
```

| Pro_fecha | Pro_nombre | Pro_numerodoc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3-1-2022 | Manzana | . Tram1 |
| 4-1-2022 | Pera | . Trap1 |
| 4-1-2022 | Piña | . Trapi1 |
| 6-1-2022 | Manzana | . Tram2 |
| 3-1-2022 | Durazno | . Trad1 |
| 8-1-2022 | Platano | . Trap1 |
| 9-1-2022 | Platano | . Trap2 |
| 14-1-2022 | Manzana | . Tram3 |
| 7-1-2022 | Piña | . Trapi2 |

Lo que necesito es obtener el último número de documento de transferencia de la fecha máxima de cada producto.
Es decir:

| Pro_fecha | Pro_nombre | Pro_numerodoc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4-1-2022 | Pera | . Trap1 |
| 3-1-2022 | Durazno | . Trad1 |
| 9-1-2022 | Platano | . Trap2 |
| 14-1-2022 | Manzana | . Tram3 |
| 7-1-2022 | Piña | . Trapi2 |

Estuve intentando con la siguiente línea

```
SELECT * 
FROM Productos 
WHERE Pro_fecha = (SELECT MAX(Pro_fecha) FROM Productos)
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si no he entendido mal:

```
select Pro_nombre, Pro_numerodoc, MAX(Pro_fecha)
from Productos 
group by Pro_nombre, Pro_numerodoc
```

Esto te dará para cada `Pro_nombre` y `Pro_numerodoc` la última fecha.